# PHP simplify range creation

Tags: php, range, simplify

I wrote this code to generate range of numbers.

Can someone help me simplify this code. I assume that it can be done in much more simpler and cleaner way, but don't know how ?

```
$variant_ids = 'AB0000001, AB0000002, AB0000003 - AB0000010, AB0000011 - AB0000020, AB0000021, AB0000022';
$delimiter = ',';
$range_delimiter = '-';

$variant_ids = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode($delimiter, $variant_ids)), 'strlen');

if (is_array($variant_ids)) {
    foreach ($variant_ids as &$variant_id) {
        if (strpos($variant_id, $range_delimiter) !== FALSE && substr_count($variant_id, $range_delimiter) == 1) {
            $variant_range_id = array_map('trim', explode($range_delimiter, $variant_id));
            $variant_id = array();
            for ($i = $variant_range_id[0]; $i <= $variant_range_id[1]; $i++) {
                $variant_id[] = $i;
            }
            $variant_id = implode($delimiter, $variant_id);
        }
    }
}

$variant_ids = implode($delimiter, $variant_ids);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($variant_ids); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Can you tell me what are you trying to do in simple words? Also any expected out put

Comment: I have a custom form in admin backend of website, where use can select certain products based on their ids. Now user has requirement that he can enter products in range as given above in `$variant_ids` and the system should select all the products between the range as well.

Comment: Hence I sanitize users inputed product ids and fill the gap between the range before searching the products database with these ids.

Comment: if the prefix are same then you could use `range()`

Comment: @Nouphal.M I decided to go with `range`, but `for` loop seems much efficient. http://www.php.net/function.range#85331

Answer (score 1):

Interesting concept that I believe that PHP’s built in [`range`](http://php.net/range) function can handle well.  Reworked your logic to work with the concept as arrays using [`range`](http://php.net/range), [`str_pad`](http://php.net/str_pad) & some regex juggling. Not perfect, but based on your original code’s needs it seems to be a nice alternative if I do say so myself.

```
// Set the basics
$raw_variant_ids = 'AB0000001, AB0000002, AB0000003 - AB0000010, AB0000011 - AB0000020, AB0000021, AB0000022';
$delimiter = ',';
$range_delimiter = '-';
$variant_ids = array();

// Explode the $raw_variant_ids to generate an array.
$range_array = explode($delimiter, $raw_variant_ids);

// Roll through the $range_array.
foreach ($range_array as $range_value) {

  // Split the range value.
  $range_split = explode($range_delimiter, $range_value);

  // If the range split has two items, generate a range. Or else, just as a straight id.
  if (count($range_split) == 2) {

    // Get the numbers for the start & end of the range.
    $range_number_start = trim(preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]/is', '', $range_split[0]));
    $range_number_end = trim(preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]/is', '', $range_split[1]));

    // Get the letters for the start of the range. 
    $alpha_prefix = trim(preg_replace('/[0-9]/is', '', $range_split[0]));

    // Get the length of the numbers based on the start number.
    $id_length = strlen($range_number_start);

    // Now use 'range()' to generate a range.
    $range_span_array = range($range_number_start, $range_number_end);

    // Roll through the $range_span_array.
    foreach ($range_span_array as $range_span_array_value) {
      $variant_ids[] = $alpha_prefix . str_pad($range_span_array_value, $id_length, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
  }
  else {
    foreach ($range_split as $range_split_value) {
      $variant_ids[] = trim($range_split_value);
    }
  }

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($variant_ids);
echo '</pre>';
```